# apirtc cordova on android 4.4 fails

Tags: android, webrtc

Not sure why or when this happened but if I include apiRTC.init in my app, it fails, if I comment out that line, it works.  No issue with Android 5 and newer or IOS, just with device running 4.4

Is there a fix anyone knows, or do I just have to dump support for these devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it worked installing [Crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview), it gives you WebRTC support until 4.2

Since Android 5.0 WebRTC support is native on Android.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: last time i tried to use crosswalk it broke other stuff.  So i try to avoid it.